# Subclassing of SupportMapFragment in ViewPager wont show map toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

**Background**

I'm implementing a detailed view over a custom location. The activity uses a ViewPager holding different fragments where one should be a SupportMapFragment. I'm testing on a Moto E using 5.0.2.


**Problem**

When a marker is pressed a map toolbar should slide in from the right. This toolbar does not show. All other controls such as compass and the "pan to my location" button shows. When I do it the normal way with an Activity that has a fragment coded in the XML the controls slide in as they should.


I've also tried adding the fragment to an activity the usual way, like this:

```
Fragment fragment = MapFragment.newInstance(title, lat, lng);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.testMapContainer, fragment).commit();
```

**Implementation**

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

private final static String TITLE_KEY = "titleKey";
    private final static String LATITUDE_KEY = "latitudeKey";
    private final static String LONGITUDE_KEY = "longitudeKey";

    private final static float ZOOM = 14;

    private String title;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public MapFragment() {
        super();
    }

    public static MapFragment newInstance(String title, double latitude,  double longitude) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(TITLE_KEY, title);
        bundle.putDouble(LATITUDE_KEY, latitude);
        bundle.putDouble(LONGITUDE_KEY, longitude);

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        title = bundle.getString(TITLE_KEY);
        latitude = bundle.getDouble(LATITUDE_KEY);
        longitude = bundle.getDouble(LONGITUDE_KEY);

        getMapAsync(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng targetLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(targetLatLng, ZOOM));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(title)
                .position(targetLatLng));
    }
}

Does anyone know what the problem may be? I'm sure it has something to do with my implementation of the SupportMapFragment.

**EDIT:**
The problem was in the XML of the Activity that is hosting the ViewPager. The MapToolbar is there but off screen. I can barely see it if i rotate the device. If I collapse the appbar before viewing the map tab the MapToolbar is fully visible.
[image: XML]
[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]
[image: Collapsed]
How can I fix the XML so the MapToolbar is always visible (and enables the collapsing of the toolbar)?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, it can popup the `MapToolbar` in the project, take look at `UpcomingFragment` [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/MapTab-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bojie/materialtest/fragments/UpcomingFragment.java) to set up the map.

For the whole project, you can get [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/MapTab-android) to test on. Just go to `third tab`, and `click the marker`, it will pop up the `MapToolbar` behind the red button. In your project, you don't have the red button, so it doesn't matter.

Sample code for setting map:

```
public class UpcomingFragment extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment mMapView;

    public static UpcomingFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        UpcomingFragment fragment = new UpcomingFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming, container, false);
        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());


        switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity())) {
            case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
                mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
                if (mapView != null) {
                    map = mapView.getMap();
                    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
                    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }
                break;
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SERVICE MISSING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UPDATE REQUIRED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

And related XML for this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.bojie.materialtest.fragments.UpcomingFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I cloned your repo and it worked. However - it does not work when I implement it like you (with a MapView and calls to MapsInitializer, onCreate, onDestroy, onLowMemory. I also tried adding onResume and onSaveInstanceState but no cigarr). I tried both with the deprecated method getMap and getMapAsync. Whats the next step? :O Getting crazy here.

Comment: What's the problem? Can you show your `logcat`? Have you changed your xml layout for `MapView`?

Comment: @bijang That wasn't the issue. Read my edit please :)